# lottery Simulation Compile Issue

Tags: c

I have started to write a lottery simulation program using C programming,however when i compile the program i get a compile error that i do not understand.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    //Welcome the User to the Program
        puts("============================");
        puts("         WELCOME TO         ");
        puts("============================");
        puts("  PROJECT : JACKPOT DREAMS  ");
        puts("============================");
    //Rogers 6 Original Numbers
        int nums[6] = { 5, 11, 15, 33, 42, 43 };

    //Ask how many years to simulate
        int years = 0;
        printf("How many years would you like to sleep for? :");
        scanf("%d", &years);
        printf("Ok. I will now play the lottery %d year(s)");
        printf("Sleep Tight :)....");
    //Generate Random Numbers
        int ctr;
        int randnums[6];
        srand(time(NULL));
        for( ctr = 0; ctr < 6; ctr++ ) randnums[ctr] = (rand() % 50);

    //Check Numbers with Rogerns numbers
        int win;
        for( ctr = 0; ctr < 6; ctr++ ) (randnums[ctr] == nums[ctr]) ? win = 1 : win = 0;




    return 0;
}
```

This is the compile error that i get:

```
LotteryNumbers.c:29:79: error: expression is not assignable
  ...= 0; ctr < 6; ctr++ ) (randnums[ctr] == nums[ctr]) ? win = 1 : win = 0;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
4 warnings and 1 error generated.
```

Comment: Aside: note that `rand() % 50` gives you a number in the range `0` to `49`. I don't think `0` is usually a lottery number (but it is in roulette). You'll also need a way not to duplicate the numbers, you can look for the Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
for( ctr = 0; ctr < 6; ctr++ ) (randnums[ctr] == nums[ctr]) ? win = 1 : win = 0;
```

to:

```
for( ctr = 0; ctr < 6; ctr++ ) win = (randnums[ctr] == nums[ctr]) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: also fix your warnings!

Comment: Thank you this has worked, can i ask you one more thing how would i get the code to loop and to print out if the numbers had matched?

Comment: I think you'd need to wrap both of your existing for loops into an outer for loop the iterates over the number of years.

Comment: Add this line after your srand call: `while (years-- > 0) {`, and then put this line after the 2nd for loop: `}`.

Comment: i did this but it still does not repeat?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because the syntax when using the [ternary operator](https://www.cprogramming.com/reference/operators/ternary-operator.html) is:

```
<condition> ? <true-case-code> : <false-case-code>;
```

Thus in your case:

```
for( ctr = 0; ctr < 6; ctr++ ) win = (randnums[ctr] == nums[ctr]) ? 1 : 0;
```

However this doesn't that all the numbers match, it just sets `win` to the result of the current number being checked. To check if all the numbers match you can try:

```
int win = 1;
for( ctr = 0; ctr < 6; ctr++ )
{
    if(randnums[ctr] != nums[ctr])
    {
        win = 0;
        break; // if there's a mismatch we don't need to continue
    }
}
```