# How to? - Lottery Simulation (C)

Tags: c

i have written a C program that will simulate lottery draws of the course of X amount of years that were inputted by the user, once the the amount of years have been inputted it will simulate a lottery draw each week for however many years. 
the program also need to print out if the pre inputted numbers ( already in the code) match, and also to print out how many times the numbers matched e.g.

- 6 numbers matched ()
- 5 numbers matched ()
- etc.

This is the code that i have so far, everything compiled and runs fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    //Welcome the User to the Program
    puts("============================");
    puts("       WELCOME TO       ");
    puts("============================");
    puts("  PROJECT : JACKPOT DREAMS  ");
    puts("============================");

    //Rogers 6 Original Numbers
    int nums[6] = { 5, 11, 15, 33, 42, 43 };

    //Ask how many years to simulate
    int years = 0;
    printf("How many years would you like to sleep for? :\n");
    scanf("%d", &years);
    printf("Ok. I will now play the lottery %d year(s)\n",years);
    printf("Sleep Tight :)....\n");

    //Generate Random Numbers
    int ctr;
    int randnums[6];
    srand(time(NULL));
    while (years-- > 0) {
        for( ctr = 0; ctr < 6; ctr++ ) randnums[ctr] = (rand() % 50);

        //Check Numbers with Rogerns numbers
        int win = 1;
        for( ctr = 0; ctr < 6; ctr++ )
        {
            if(randnums[ctr] != nums[ctr])
            {
                win = 0;
                break; // if there's a mismatch we don't need to continue
            }
        }


        return 0;
    }

}
```

does anyone know how i would do this?

Comment: `does anyone know how i would do this?` sorry I don't get this question, you just said `This is the code that i have so far, everything compiled and runs fine`

Comment: You should fix your indentation first.This is reeeally important.

Comment: You have to _sort_ your generated numbers prior to matching them with Rogers numbers. And make sure, that no number is duplicate.

Comment: @Ctx could you tell me how to do that?

Comment: @Gregmastiv `qsort(randnums, 6, sizeof(int), comp);` with `int comp(const void *a, const void *b) { return *(int *)a - *(int *)b; }`

Comment: @Ctx where in my code would i place this?

Comment: just going to keep asking until someone writes this for you I guess? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55272124/lottery-simulation-compile-issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55272977/cant-work-out-this-problem-lottery-simulator-c , plus the other (at least) two questions from yesterday that apparently have been deleted.

Comment: @yano just trying to get my code to work

Comment: starting from yesterday this code has been fed to you. Some of the `printf`s are different today, but that's it. If you're an ME or something who was forced to take a coding class, then I have more sympathy. But if you're going to school for anything comp sci/eng related, you simply are going to have to put in the time and pain to learn what's going on. That involves a lot of googling, experimentation, patience, and help/tutoring if that's not enough. Presumably you're paying your school a lot of money, get your money's worth! SO isn't a place to write your program piecemeal.

Comment: if you're not sure how `qsort` (for example) works, google it, read about it, look at example code, write your own. Insert it in different places in your code, see what the results are. You'll learn a lot more that way than asking a question here every 30 min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly it seems that you `return` after looping through the first year. You should move the `return` statement outside the braces. Secondly as some comments mentioned, you should write blocks more carefully, and make correct indents.

Below I have rewritten your program, to print out if some numbers match for a given year. If all numbers match, "Winner!" is also printed. To do this I have added a few variables and `print` statements.

Hope this helps.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int
main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    //Welcome the User to the Program
    puts("============================");
    puts("         WELCOME TO         ");
    puts("============================");
    puts("  PROJECT : JACKPOT DREAMS  ");
    puts("============================");

    //Rogers 6 Original Numbers
    int nums[6] = { 5, 11, 15, 33, 42, 43 };

    //Ask how many years to simulate
    int years = 0;
    printf("How many years would you like to sleep for? :\n");
    scanf("%d", &years);
    printf("Ok. I will now play the lottery %d year(s)\n",years);
    printf("Sleep Tight :)....\n");

    //Generate Random Numbers
    int numberOfWins = 0;
    int ctr;
    int randnums[6];
    srand(time(NULL));

    int currYear = 0;
    while (years-- > 0) 
    {
        currYear++;
        for( ctr = 0; ctr < 6; ctr++ ) randnums[ctr] = (rand() % 50);

        //Check Numbers with Rogerns numbers
        int win = 1, matched = 0;
        for( ctr = 0; ctr < 6; ctr++ )
        {
            if(randnums[ctr] != nums[ctr])
            {
                win = 0;
            } else {
                matched++;
            }
        }
        numberOfWins += win;

        //If any numbers matched or win, print it.
        if (matched > 0) printf("In year: %d, %d number(s) matched\n", currYear, matched);
        if (win) printf("Winner!\n");
    }

    printf("You won %d time(s)\n", numberOfWins);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good catch about the `return`, but you should advice the OP that they are still far from completing their task: starting from *"simulate a lottery draw **each week** for however many years"* up to the fact that `rand() % 50` is unlikely a good way to simulate a lottery extraction (0 is valid? what about repeated values?) and that the match check incorrectly assumes that the values are sorted (`rand()` may be bad, but not *that* bad).